# I receive this warning from google play

Tags: android, google-play, warnings

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> We’re contacting you because **** (version 2) handles or requests
>   installed apps user data. Apps like this must comply with the
>   Prominent Disclosure requirements of our User Data policy.
>
> Action required: Make sure your app fulfills the Prominent Disclosure
>   requirements of our User Data policy. If these requirements are not
>   fulfilled within 30 days, your app may be removed from Google Play.
>   Alternatively, you can remove any requests for sensitive permissions
>   or user data within your app. You can also choose to unpublish your
>   app.
>
> If you need to make changes to your app, please follow these steps:
>   Read through the Prominent Disclosure requirements of our User Data
>   policy. Post a privacy policy within the app itself. Sign in to your
>   Play Console and post a privacy policy in the designated field on the
>   app’s Store listing page. Unless the user data is related to app
>   functionality described prominently in the app’s listing on Google
>   Play or in the app interface, you must display a prominent disclosure
>   mechanism to users within the app, highlighting how their data will be
>   used. This disclosure mechanism must be shown before collecting or
>   transmitting any user data. This disclosure mechanism must require
>   affirmative user action (e.g. tap to accept, tick a check-box, a
>   verbal command, etc.) in order to accept. If you have other apps in
>   your catalog that handle sensitive user or device information, make
>   sure they comply with these requirements as well.
>
> If you’ve read through our policies and feel this warning was sent in
>   error, you can reach out to our policy support team. Thanks for
>   supporting Google Play, The Google Play Team

I think they mistaked my app does only have these permissions :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
```

but I use admob.
What should I do ?

Comment: *What should I do ?* ask google instead of random people on stack overflow, just like they tell you in their message

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic